# How does compare method work?

Tags: java

The program sorts the array in ascending order but on swapping `id` and `compareid` in the return statement the array sorts in descending order but it has no effect on the output of `System.out.println(e[1].compareTo(e[0]));` it returns `1` in both cases. Why is it so?

```
package example;

import java.util.Arrays;

class Example implements Comparable<Example> {
    int id;

    public int compareTo(Example ob) {
        int compareid = ob.id;
        return Integer.compare(id, compareid); // problem
    }
}

class comparableinterface {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Example e[] = new Example[3];
        e[0] = new Example();
        e[0].id = 2;
        e[1] = new Example();
        e[1].id = 3;
        e[2] = new Example();
        e[2].id = 0;
        Arrays.sort(e);
        for (Example temp : e) {
            System.out.println(temp.id);
        }
        System.out.println(e[1].compareTo(e[0]));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your comparison is being performed after you have sorted the array, and Arrays.sort(e) changes the contents of the array e.

Move

```
System.out.println(e[1].compareTo(e[0]));
```

to before the sort, and it will behave as you expected.

Answer (score 1):

The result of compareTo reflects a certain order between the object and the argument. This will always be +1 between the first and second in a sorted array, sorted according to whatever is expressed by compareTo.

It is *not* an indication of the numeric relation!

Comment: I think this is one of the few correct answers here. I meant the same in my answer so +1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

Because in order to sort your array ascending/descending you also change your `compareTo` method in `example` to compare for < respectively > (i.e. you swap the logic in the compareTo method). That's why it gives you the same result from `System.out.println(e[1].compareTo(e[0]));`. Basically after the change, your `compareTo` does not check for "is smaller" any more but checks for "is bigger". So even though `System.out.println(e[1].compareTo(e[0]));` returns 1 in both cases, in the first case it tells you "e[1] is bigger than e[0]" and in the second case it tells you "e[1] is smaller than e[0]". It's kind of tricky, think about it.

Answer (score 0):

You are using [`Integer.compare(id,compareid)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare%28int,%20int%29) in your overrided `compareTo(Example ob)` method, and for your information,

> **Integer.compare(id,compareid)** returns the value *0 if id == compareid*; a value *less than 0 if id < compareid*; and a value *greater than 0 if id > compareid*.

And you are calling `compareTo(Example ob)` after sorting the array, this is why the method always returning `1`.

Try calling `compareTo(Example ob)` before sorting the array.

Answer (score 0):

> compareTo method is referred to as its natural comparison method.
>
> The natural ordering for a class C is said to be consistent with
> equals if and only if e1.compareTo(e2) == 0 has the same boolean value
> as e1.equals(e2) for every e1 and e2 of class C.

[Ref](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)

See also the java.utils.Arrays.mergeSort() source code to see how compareTo is used to sort an array:

```
for (int j=i; j>low &&
             ((Comparable) dest[j-1]).compareTo(dest[j])>0; j--)
                    swap(dest, j, j-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call the compareTo() method on an instance of an Integer, not the static compare()

Try this:

```
int id;
public int compareTo(Example ob) {

        Integer compareid = ob.id;
        return compareid.compareTo(id);
    }
```

Comment: Really? I get output: 3
2
0
1 - then process terminates

Comment: Ok It's calling the compareTo method of the Integer class :)